# Sprint boot problem while using hibernate session factory and PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.5, sessionfactory

I have implemented One demo projects and here I have listed out the dependency used my project.

1. spring-boot-2.0.1
2. spring-data-jpa-2.0.6
3. spring-core-5.0.5
4. hibernate-core-5.4.1
5. postgresql-42.2.2

I have used Microsoft SQL server with SQL configuration in application.yml and MasterDatabaseConfig.java file its working fine able to get the result from SQL database.

While I changed the database from SQL server to PostgreSQL I'm not getting Connection in sessionfactory its throwing error in console. Here I have given mandatory configuration files, please help me to resolve this problem.

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
</properties>

<!-- Demo project supporting dependencies jars -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot JPA jars for Database relationship and object processing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot web jars for application component -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot test jars for Testing utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies jar Database connections and connection pool 
        management -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

MasterDatabaseConfig.java

```
package com.encagementstudio.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

/**
 * Configuration of the master database which holds information about tenants in
 * the application.
 *
 *
 * @since (September 2018)
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.encagmentstudio.jpa.entity", "com.encagementstudio.dao" })
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {
private static final Logger            LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDatabaseConfig.class);

/**
 * Master database configuration properties like user name, password, etc.
 */
@Autowired
private MasterDatabaseConfigProperties masterDbProperties;

/**
 * Creates the master data source bean which is required for creating the entity
 * manager factory bean <br/>
 * <br/>
 * Note that using names for beans is not mandatory but it is a good practice to
 * ensure that the intended beans are being used where required.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
public DataSource masterDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setUsername(this.masterDbProperties.getUsername());
    ds.setPassword(this.masterDbProperties.getPassword());
    ds.setJdbcUrl(this.masterDbProperties.getUrl());
    ds.setDriverClassName(this.masterDbProperties.getDriverClassName());
    ds.setPoolName(this.masterDbProperties.getPoolName());
    // HikariCP settings
    // Maximum number of actual connection in the pool
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(this.masterDbProperties.getMaxPoolSize());
    // Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
    ds.setMinimumIdle(this.masterDbProperties.getMinIdle());
    // Maximum waiting time for a connection from the pool
    ds.setConnectionTimeout(this.masterDbProperties.getConnectionTimeout());
    // Maximum time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool
    ds.setIdleTimeout(this.masterDbProperties.getIdleTimeout());
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    MasterDatabaseConfig.LOG.info("Setup of masterDataSource succeeded.");
    return ds;
}

/**
 * Creates the entity manager factory bean which is required to access the JPA
 * functionalities provided by the JPA persistence provider, i.e. Hibernate in
 * this case. <br/>
 *
 *
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean(name = "masterSessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean masterSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    try {
        MasterDatabaseConfig.LOG.info("-------masterSessionFactory-----------");
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.masterDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.*");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        MasterDatabaseConfig.LOG.info("------------------");
        e.printStackTrace();
        MasterDatabaseConfig.LOG.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}


/**
 * The properties for configuring the Hibernate.
 *
 * @return
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, true);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.FORMAT_SQL, true);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
    return properties;
}


}
```

application.yml:

```
#Server
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /demo       
---
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    hibernate:
      naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: none      
multitenancy: 
  mtapp: 
    master: 
      datasource:
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{database_name}
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        connectionTimeout: 20000
        maxPoolSize: 10
        idleTimeout: 300000
        minIdle: 10
        poolName: masterdb-connection-pool
```

EncagementStudioDaoImpl.java

```
package com.encagementstudio.daoimpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.encagementstudio.dao.IEncagementStudioDao;
import com.encagmentstudio.jpa.entity.NodePosition;
import com.encagmentstudio.jpa.entity.WorkflowsEntity;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class EncagementStudioDaoImpl implements IEncagementStudioDao {
    private static final Logger g_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncagementStudioDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory      sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        Session session = null;
        String value="ok";
        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tenant.tenantdetails");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            EncagementStudioDaoImpl.g_logger.error("Exception Occurred at getDetails" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

SpringBoot main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Problem:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-01 14:26:03.360 ERROR 2700 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Tried way:
I have excluded JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration in spring boot class then not getting any problem during startup. While accessing DAO class i'm Facing problem like below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@62472467] bound to thread [http-nio-8081-exec-2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:213) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.afterCompletion(OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.afterCompletion(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.triggerAfterCompletion(HandlerExecutionChain.java:174) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1087) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

Based on the above dependency I need to execute my springboot applications.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used EntityManagerFactory for sessionfactory object, its solved.

```
@Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
        @Qualifier("currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
        CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.*.*");
    emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
    emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("tenantdb-persistence-unit");
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT,MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER,connectionProvider);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER,tenantResolver);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, true);
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
    properties.put(AvailableSettings.POOL_SIZE, 2);
    properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");

    emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    TenantDatabaseConfig.LOG.info("tenantEntityManagerFactory set up successfully!");
    return emfBean;
}
```

Comment: Why? You can let Spring Boot configure all of th is for you, why are you doing this manually?